# How to install a public Beta version of macOS in a Fusion VM?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, beta-seed-program

I'd like to run the latest public beta of High Sierra (10.13.4 Beta 1) in a VMWare Fusion VM.

I already have a Fusion VM running High Sierra 10.13.3, but trying to upgrade it to 10.13.4 with the App Store gets stuck just showing a black screen with the Apple logo after downloading and initiating the upgrade process (see Screenshot).

[image]

Normally I would just set up a new VM with the version I like to use. But I can't find a way to just download the public Beta to use it as an installation medium for the VM. Of course I can find the public Beta in the App Store of my macOS host system, too, but the App Store is only giving me the option of downloading **and** installing it, which is not what I want.

Does anyone know of a way to get public Beta version of macOS installed in a Fusion VM?

Comment: Hi, I have a similar problem. Upgrading to 10.13.4 public beta 1 works and I get a VM with a very high resolution. Scaling the window brings to a black screen (in the VM) and a stuck VM. I have to perform a "Power on to firmware" to be able to reboot. After the reboot the same situation with the wrong resolution.

Comment: @Matteo Yes, in the meantime I got to that point, too. It's a bit annoying how difficult/badly supported macOS virtualization generally is.

Comment: I tried with the public beta 2: same result